# Java Creating a date in PST returns a date in PDT

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, dst

```
public class TestTimeZone {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", "PST");
    TimeZone.setDefault(null);
    Date d1 = new Date(1257062400000L);
    Date d2 = new Date(d1.getTime() + 3600000);
    DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH");
    System.out.println(f.format(d1).equals(f.format(d2)));  // true
    System.out.println(d1.equals(f.parse(f.format(d1))));   // false
    System.out.println(d1);                                 // Sun Nov 01 01:00:00 PDT 2009
    System.out.println(d2);                                 // Sun Nov 01 01:00:00 PST 2009
  }
}
```

- `d1` and `d2` are clearly different, so their formats shouldn't be same.
- when you format and parse `d1`, you get `d2`
- I set time zone to PST and then create `d1`, it should be created as a `PST` date, why is it getting created as a PDT date?

Comment: My answer explains why you're seeing the current behaviour. I can't give you any suggestions as to how to proceed, as I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

> d1 and d2 are clearly different, so their formats shouldn't be same

Well they wouldn't be if you had an unambiguous format - but you don't. (Heck, even leaving time zones aside you're only formatting to the hour, so it's trivial to create non-equal `Date` values that format to the same string.)

You're formatting the local time in the system default time zone, which means that if the time zone's UTC offset goes back (as it does in America/Los_Angeles on November 1st 2015, for example) you can have the same local time occurring twice... so you get the same string output for two different times. When you call `parse`, how are you expecting the formatter to infer information as to which of the original values you meant?

Note that there's no such thing as a `java.util.Date` in a particular time zone - a `Date` just represents a number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

Also note that PST isn't really a time zone identifier - you'd be better off using the IANA identifiers such as America/Los_Angeles. If you really want a time zone of UTC-8 with no DST changes, you can use Etc/GMT+8 instead. The +8 (instead of -8) is due to the use of Posix-style offsets here. Somewhat confusing... Another alternative would be to call `TimeZone.setDefault(new SimpleTimeZone(-28800000, "UTC-8"))`.

Comment: My problem is, if I've set the timezone to PST in the beginning, then formatting a date should happen according to PST. Since in PST, that milliseconds mean different than the do in PDT. So whatever they mean in PST, should be the result of `format`. It should either be Nov 1 0th hour or 2nd hour. Then parsing back will give the same time.

Comment: @prongs: But as I said, you haven't really set the time zone to "PST" (despite appearing to do so) - you've set the time zone to "Pacific Time". If you look at `TimeZone.getDefault()` you'll see that it *does* have DST. That's what my final paragraph is about - if you really want a time zone which never adjusts its UTC offset, don't specify it via an abbreviation such as PST.